# SeriesData sucks when it can. How do I keep SeriesData from sucking?

Tags: series-expansion, expression-manipulation

When I run

```
Series[f[x]*Sin[x],{x,0,3}, Analytic->False]
```

I get:

> `f[x](x-x^3/3+O[x]^4)`

as expected.  In `FullForm`, this is

```
Times[f[x],SeriesData[x,0,List[1,0,Rational[-1,6]],1,4,1]]
```

But when I take this output and run it as an input, the `SeriesData` ends up forgetting that `f[x]` is not supposed to be treated as an analytic function, and it *sucks* up and expands out the `f[x]`:

> `f[0]x + f'[0] x^2 + (-f[0]/6 + f''[0]/2)x^2 + O[x]^4`

How do I keep `SeriesData` from *sucking* up nearby symbols?

Comment: How about `Hold`ing it?

Comment: What if you replace `f` with `\[FormalF]`?

Comment: How about `SetOptions[Series, Analytic -> False]`

Comment: This would work to answer the question as posed: `f/:f[r__]s_SeriesData:=Defer@Times[f[r],s]` The idea is to suppress the evaluation when `f` appears in a product with `SeriesData`. The suppression would only work for that specific function. I'm not sure if you want the sucking to stop for *all* symbols (I wouldn't recommend that because it could unintentionally interfere with expansions of other expressions).

Comment: @Jens I am trying to find the built-in rule associated with `SeriesData` that actually sucks up the outside symbols.  However after `Unprotect[SeriesData]`, I can't find it in the list generated by `UpValues[SeriesData]`.  My hope is to modify the appropriate built-in rule so that it specifically doesn't bring `f[x]` into the `SeriesData`.  Do you know how to find that rule?

Comment: It could be that this is more deeply hidden, because of the behavior of `O`. Anything with `O` turns into `SeriesData`, but the documentation states that `O` is **contagious**. So perhaps the sucking is caused by this contagiousness, and I don't know where it's implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you first

```
SetOptions[Series, Analytic -> False]
```

and then wrap f[x] in HoldForm,

```
Series[HoldForm[f[x]]*Sin[x],{x,0,3}]
```

then when you take this output and run it as an input, HoldForm[f[x]] is not expanded out.